# escaping spaces in local url

Tags: objective-c

i have the following code to try and load a local html page in a cocoa app...

```
NSString *basePath = @"file//Users/david/Documents/My Project/index.html";
NSString *escapedPath = [basePath stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

NSURL*url=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedPath];
NSURLRequest*request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSLog(@"current file is %@", url);
```

Unfortunately, the url is always null, and if i look at the value of escapedPath i see '%20' escaping the space. however, this doesn't work in local. is there a stringBy function that escapes correctly for a local path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For local paths you need to use `fileURLWithPath:`

See the docs here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html